# How do I choose the right microcontroller？

Tags: microcontroller, microchip

I have a new project that requires deploying deep learning algorithms on embedded chips.I'm new to this field, so I'm not quite sure what metrics do I need to choose based on.Such as **how much RAM, flash memory, and cpu performance**.The requirements of the project are as follows:

- Under $15
- Can be used for custom deep learning algorithm development.Having a suitable development framework,like CMSIS-NN
- The size of quantized model is 640KB.The model is DTLN

I have searched for some possible microcontrollers before I asked:

- STM32F4,STM32H7,STM32L4,STM32MP1 series
- ESP32-S3,ESP32-S3-PICO-1

Comment: I would start by defining the data type and number of multiple-add operations needed per cycle.  If you need floating point, no point in looking at systems that lack it or cannot do enough operations per second. Then go from there.

Comment: it's sort of up to you - CPU performance only affects how fast your inference is. How fast do you need it to be? Does your application need to process 100 1024x1024 RGB images per second? 1 128x128 mono image every 5 seconds? Flash memory depends on what you want to do in addition to your model - you need enough flash to store your model, and the rest of the code, and maybe your input data? Depends on your application. RAM also depends on what you want to do - how many sets of input data will you have to hold at once (in addition to your model)?

Comment: One of the main distinguishing factors between microprocessors are the "peripherals" that it has. Things like timers and pins that can be used for pulse width modulation, or support for various communication protocols including support for wireless protocols. etc. etc. etc. How is your micro-controller going to communicate with the rest of your system?

Comment: @BeB00 Thank you for your advice. My input data is audio, I will cut the audio into 512-1024 length frames, the data type is float. Input data, models, and code add up to no more than 1024KB. My need for processing speed is to be able to process this audio in real time using the model.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Perhaps using I2C communication? I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Killuaisaack you'll need to see how long your inference will take. You can estimate the raw performance you need by looking at how many operations are required for an inference - this will give you the order of magnitude of the speed you need, then you can look at some options in that speed category and go from there

Comment: If you can afford to just get one and try it, you could try it. You'll hopefully get a feel for what you need more of and what you need less of, on the first one you try, and then you can make a better informed decision?

Comment: Go through your model and figure out how many floating point operations per second that is.

Comment: Is the MCU just gonna sit on a PCB and ponder great matters or will it interact with the world around it? :) Picking one with sufficient speed and memory is the easy part - what about hardware peripherals? Number of GPIO? In what environment will it be used? What supply voltage? And so on.

Comment: Furthermore you should probably make it a requirement that the MCU must have a FPU. My experience of AI programming is limited, but it seems very likely that you'll need floating point and/or fuzzy logic support. Meaning Cortex M4 or bigger, most likely. Also try to poke around trying to determine if one particular MCU vendor or the other is pushing for similar application use. I would imagine that the vendors that are big in the car industry (mainly NXP and Renesas) will have plenty of suitable options.

Comment: "Under $15" This doesn't say much without estimating a yearly volume.

Comment: I think you have to raise your budget a bit more. Arduino Nano 33 BLE is a good choice https://store.arduino.cc/products/arduino-nano-33-ble It costs 22.8 USD. If you ever consider doing a big-budget project for deep learning, you can consider NVDIA Jetson https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/Nanosaur___The_smallest_NVIDIA_Jetson_dinosaur_robot.html